# Everyone is attracted to me!

Tags: riddle, physics

Everyone in the world is attracted to me even though I'm the most abhorrent and repulsive creature to roam the earth. Though I am human, exploit no human weakness, and there are much more suitable males. Even those who hate me. Everywhere I go, I have the same effect on anyone, independent of sex, religion, personal preferences, or sexuality. I do not conceal my hideous features, and many prefer to avoid me. In the same way, I'm attracted to everyone else. How is this possible?

Comment: I think you need to stop posting low quality puzzles and spend some time making some higher quality ones.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Great idea. );

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil better?

Comment: @Deusovi I would like this riddle to have a second chance. If you don't think so because it is too broad, then please suggest ways that I may improve it.

Comment: If you would like to have this reopened, I suggest editing it to remove any unwanted solutions given in the answer below, as well as cleaning up formatting. If you do that, then it's possible that some users will see the improvements and vote to reopen it. The more obvious it is that the question was significantly improved, the more likely it is to be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @manshu

> You are a toilet.

PREVIOUS ANSWER before it was edited to something different:

I could be because

> You are a magnet.
> You are the last living creature.
> You are wearing a strong perfume.
> You are in a disguise.

Comment: "Though I am human"

Comment: @tommy you are `you`

Comment: @MukulKumar does that imply what i think it does?